# How to create session token for my file on AWS S3 if it connected to other CDN provider?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cdn

I have some video file stored on AWS S3 and I want to secure these files by adding session token with specific expiry time on the video URLs for preventing unauthorized access.

I know the s3 SDK can generate temporary credentials with Cloudfront to achieve this.

However, if I connected S3 to other CDN provider such as cloudflare. Will these temporary credentials work perfectly?

For example, my video file is stored on s3 -> http://files.video.com.s3.amazonaws.com/video.mp4

The cloudflare cdn url is -> http://files.video.com/video.mp4

If i generated temporary credentials for the file and access the url -> http://files.video.com/video.mp4?token=4180da90a6973bc8bd801bfe49f04a&expirey=1526231040535

Will it work?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're referring to S3 [Presigned URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html). No, if your S3 bucket is private, CloudFlare will not be able to generate presigned URLs to access your files. AWS CloudFront uses an [Origin Access Identity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html) to resolve this issue. However with 3rd party CDNs, this is not possible.

There are 2 ways you could achieve better security ([source](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/how-to-protect-an-amazon-s3-storage-from-using-it-directly/23291)).

- Make your bucket public but [restrict the allowed IPs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-3) for your S3 bucket to only [CloudFlare IPs](https://www.cloudflare.com/ips/).
- Make your bucket private and use [CloudFlare workers](https://www.cloudflare.com/products/cloudflare-workers/) to authorize its GET requests

Comment: Thanks. Learned a lot from your opinions. So, is it really depending on whether the 3rd party CDN providers have providing the temporary credentials for their presigned URLs? Although I created temporary credentials using S3 SDK, if the 3rd party CDN providers do not support. It's also failed?